# Lodash _.lowerCase method

Tags: node.js, lodash

I am a beginner to Lodash and I want to convert the string 'AnotherPost' to string 'anotherpost'. There's no gap between another and post. But when I use

```js
let title = _.lowerCase('AnotherPost');

console.log(title);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It logs the string 'another post' with the space which I don't want. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `"AnotherPost".toLowerCase()`? I don't think you need Lodash for this. It explicitly adds spaces in some circumstances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_.lowerCase()` method converts a string to lower case with spaces between the words.

Use to Lodash's `_.toLower()` or the JS `String.toLowerCase()`:

```js
console.log(_.lowerCase('AnotherPost')); // another post

console.log(_.toLower('AnotherPost')); // anotherpost

console.log('AnotherPost'.toLowerCase()); // anotherpost
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I was able to make the code snippet but couldn't link node to it. How do you do that?

Comment: Look at this post - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: But it don't tell you how to link node. I can make the snippet but node still don't work.

Comment: What do you by "link node"?

Comment: I mean does the node.js code work in the js snippet or you need to do something additional?

Comment: This runs in the browser, so you don't need (and can't) start node.js. Just paste the script tag in the html section - `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

Comment: I've edited your question, and added the snippet. You can edit your post, and see how it looks like.